# ServiceNotFoundException: The service "my.facebook.user" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_user.user_manager"

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I'm using the fosFacebookBundle for symfony2.
I followed the instructions from the installation guide but now I don't know what I must change in the security section for the userManager:

```
services:
my.facebook.user:
    class: Acme\MyBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
    arguments:
        facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
        userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
        validator: "@validator"
        container: "@service_container"
```

I think I must refer my UserRepository but I don't know the right syntax. 
Can anybody help me for this?

The second question is, how can I call the provider in my controller?

Comment: Did you install FOSUserBundle?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in FOSFacebookBundle you have to use FOSUserBundle or use this for configuration and take this till your signin button after that code will be something like,

```
$facebook = $this->get('facebook');
$facebook_user = $facebook->getUser();
$userProfile = $facebook->api('/'.$facebook_user);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($userProfile,true).'</pre>';
```

This works for me, don't know work for you or not! but i will suggest you to try it once.